# Controlling parent scope variables from child state in ui.router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I just wanted to ask about nesting views in one state and how to share some context between those views.

I just have such index.html

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ui-view="header"></div>
  <div ui-view="content"></div>
  <div ui-view="footer"></div>
</body>
```

And I have a header.html that is rendered inside `ui-view` named `header` like this:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

This is very simple template but it shows the problem that I have.
When `ui-view` named `content` component is rendered It depends on route (state). The `header` and `footer` are defined in abstract parent `root` state so I don't need to repeat them in child states. Child states only define `content` for parent `root` state (`index.html`).

How to control for example `title` scope variable in `header.html` from child state so I can easy switch `title` in this `header` view based on state. Every example that I saw in internet assumes that there is static header and footer template without any variables.

I'm using `angularjs` and `ui.router`. Does `ui.router` define for each view in single state new context?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). They are basically objects that hold the states for the application outside of controllers (so you could use them to share data between two controllers for example).

There's also a [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) object that you could utilize (its a single scope available to every controller that injects it), but i'd recommend this less than first approach (especially for the future mainterance reasons - if you ever want to upgrade to angular, it doesn't have the rootScope).

Comment: See [`$rootScope` exists, but it can be used for evil](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#-rootscope-exists-but-it-can-be-used-for-evil).